# Why Django admin page redirected you too many times

Tags: django, redirect

This is my main urls file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.apiOverview),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('academy/', include('academy.urls')),
    path('administration/', include('administration.urls')),
]
```

this code working fine in localhost, but when i run it in online server works other endpoints correctly but when i use to login admin by using admin/ then showing this Error..!! I search it but unable to solve this issue. I use online rederect tool where shows 301 and 302 redirection code!! Please help me!!

Comment: urls file looks fine, problem lies in different place, i.e. have you changed anything with login process?

Comment: No,,  i just add mysql engine as mysql.connector.django instead of mysql main engine